# How to use "Tap With Positions" in robot framework?

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium, robotframework

I was using the "long press" keyword for android app automation,
but recently the selenium v4 is no longer support this keyword instead of  "Tap With Position".

I checked the AppiumLibrary, and the example shows this and I dont know how to write the script exactly..

Example:

```
@{firstFinger}  create list ${100}  ${500}
@{secondFinger} create list |${700} ${500}  
@{fingerPositions}  create list ${firstFinger}  ${secondFinger}
Sleep   1       
Tap with Positions  ${1000} @{fingerPositions}
```

https://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html#Tap%20With%20Positions

Can someone give me some leads?
Appreciate!

Comment: did you read the text which is before the code on that page?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation makes reference to a Built In method called, create list, and remember that there should be two spaces between the method name and the arguments.

A final example may look like this:

```
@{firstFinger}  create list  ${100} ${500}
Tap with Positions  ${1000}  @{firstFinger}
```

Basically, the ${1000} refers to the duration of the Tap action, and the @{firstFinger} refers to a tuple with two elements, x/y position.

From the documentation, you may also create a list of lists if multiple fingers should be tapped in the screen.